# C# 'as' Keyword and Derived Classes

Tags: c#

I am working my way through "Sams Teach Yourself C# in 21 Days", obviously, this makes me a novice programmer. Please don't be too harsh. So far, being objective, I've feel I've done quite well understanding the topics. I am not looking for the answer, but hopefully be pointed in the right direction. :)

Anyway, I have this code:

```
// EXERCISE 11.4

using System;

public class Person
{
    public string Name;

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person( string nm )
    {
        Name = nm;
    }

    public virtual void displayFullName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Person {0}", Name );
    }
}

class Employee : Person
{
    //public ushort hireYear;

    public Employee()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public Employee( string nm )
        : base( nm )
    {
    }

    public override void displayFullName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Employee: {0}", Name );
    }
}

class Contractor : Person
{
    //public string Company;

    public Contractor()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public Contractor( string nm )
        : base( nm )
    {
    }

    public override void displayFullName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Contractor: {0}", Name );
    }

    public void DisplayCompany()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Company: {0}", Company );
    }
}

class MyApplication
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person [ ] myCompany = new Person[5];
        int Counter = 0;
        string Buffer, Buffer2;

        do
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write( "\nEnter \'c\' for Contractor, \'e\' for Employee then press ENTER: " );
                Buffer = Console.ReadLine();
            } while( Buffer == "" );

            if( Buffer[0] == 'c' || Buffer[0] == 'C' )
            {
                Console.Write( "\nEnter the contractor\'s name: " );
                Buffer = Console.ReadLine();
                // DO OTHER CONTRACTOR STUFF
                Contractor Contr = new Contractor( Buffer );
                myCompany[Counter] = Contr as Person;
            }
            else if( Buffer[0] == 'e' || Buffer[0] == 'E' )
            {
                Console.Write( "\nEnter the employee\'s name: " );
                Buffer = Console.ReadLine();
                // DO OTHER EMPLOYEE STUFF
                Employee emp = new Employee( Buffer );
                myCompany[Counter] = emp as Person;
            }
            else
            {
                Person pers = new Person( "Not an Employee or Contractor" );
                myCompany[Counter] = pers;
            }

            Counter++;

        } while( Counter < 5 );

        Console.WriteLine( "\n\n\n===========================" );

        for( Counter = 0; Counter < 5; Counter++ )
        {
            if( myCompany[Counter] is Employee )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Employee: {0}", myCompany[Counter].Name );
            }
            else if( myCompany[Counter] is Contractor )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Contractor: {0}.", myCompany[Counter].Name );
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Person: {0}", myCompany[Counter].Name );
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine( "===========================" );

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

In the excercise I've to modify the Contractor or Employee class and add either a hireYear or Company data member respectively.

Which would look like this:

```
class Employee : Person
{
    public ushort hireYear;

    public Employee()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public Employee( string nm )
        : base( nm )
    {
    }

    public Employee( string nm, ushort hy )
        : base( nm )
    {
        hireYear = hy;
    }

    public override void displayFullName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Employee: {0}", Name );
    }
}
```

OR

```
class Contractor : Person
{
    public string Company;

    public Contractor()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public Contractor( string nm )
        : base( nm )
    {
    }

    public Contractor( string nm, string c )
        : base( nm )
    {
        Company = c;
    }

    public override void displayFullName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Contractor: {0}", Name );
    }

    public void DisplayCompany()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Company: {0}", Company );
    }
}
```

The changes to the MainApplication would be:

```
            if( Buffer[0] == 'c' || Buffer[0] == 'C' )
            {
                string Buffer2;

                Console.Write( "\nEnter the contractor\'s name: " );
                Buffer = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write( "\nEnter the contractor\'s company: " );
                Buffer2 = Console.ReadLine();

                Contractor Contr = new Contractor( Buffer, Buffer2 );
                myCompany[Counter] = Contr as Person;
            }
```

OR

```
            else if( Buffer[0] == 'e' || Buffer[0] == 'E' )
            {
                string BufferHireYear;

                Console.Write( "\nEnter the employee\'s name: " );
                Buffer = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write( "\nEnter the year employee was hired: " );
                BufferHireYear = Console.ReadLine();

                Employee emp = new Employee( Buffer, BufferHireYear );
                myCompany[Counter] = emp as Person;
            }
```

I am quite happy until this point, I think. My confusion starts when I need to print out the results. My thinking is that when the objects are "cast" back into the myCompany array, they are added as objects of type person. The class for Person does not contain the data members Company or HireYear, so how can I access those data members?

Thank-you for reading through this posting, I am sure someone will be able to help.

I've got to learn.

Matt

Comment: If you have feedback on the pros and cons of the book I would be happy to hear them. I was the technical reviewer of that book, and I can pass along any constructive criticism to Scott or the publishers.

Comment: Eric, so far, I am quite happy with the book. It moves about the right pace for me. I've noted a few discrepancies, but I do have an older 2002 copy. I have noticed that there is a newer version available, perhaps these have been fixed.

Comment: I don't recommend reading a nine-year-out-of-date book. We've added rather a lot to the language since then! Indeed, the book has been completely rewritten. I was the technical editor of the latest edition, by Scott Dorman. I don't know anything about the 2002 edition.

Comment: Well, I've just ordered the 2010 Edition. In my naivety I didn't think there would be too many changes. I am sure it'll save me heartache in the future. Thanks Eric!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast your objects back to `Employee` so that you can use the members defined by `Employee`.

```
Employee emp = (Employee)myCompany[Counter];
```

If `myCompany[Counter]` isn't actually an `Employee`, this will throw an `InvalidCastException`.

When putting `Employee`s in the array, you don't need to cast, since `Employee` is always convertible to `Person`.
You only need to cast explicitly if there is a chance that it won't work.

Comment: Thank-you so much. I thought that a conversion would have to happen, but didn't know which form, or where it should happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you need printing/handling that is special for each sub-type you can special case the handling of each sub type in the output code.

```
foreach (Person person in myCompany)
{
    if (person is Employee)
    {
        Employee e = (Employee)person;
        Console.WriteLine("HireYear: {0}", e.HireYear);
    // etc..
```

Another option would be for the Person base class to offer an abstract description property and each sub-class could override and then the output functions could call description when printing.

Comment: The point about the abstract description property avoids the if/else or switch.  A good guideline when doing OO is if you have large if/else or switch blocks, as a general rule, you're design is a bit off.

Comment: As usual there seems to be more than one way to do things. In your example, could you change the if( … ) to a switch? Or rather, would a switch work with objects as case arguments?

Comment: switch won't work here because "person is Employee" is an expression that get's evaluated as opposed to a switch which switches on a value.  BTW, if you want to thank me, you can up vote the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I may be jumping ahead here, but you may be interested at this point in the topic of "[polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)".  Taking advantage of polymorphism here, instead of having the calling code retrieve and print the individual details based on the type of Person, you simply tell the person to print or retrieve their own details based on what kind of person they are.  So in this case, if you make a virtual function (similar to displayFullName) that prints out the full details of this instance, you can just call that on the person, and it will execute the appropriate version based on the actual type of Person on which it was invoked.

However, you *can* also cast the instance to the specific type and access it's members as described in the other answers.

Comment: polymorphism is a good point.  Above I noted abstract description but could abstract but can also be virtual as you're pointing out.  A general guideline I always have is if you have big else/if or switch blocks handling your types, chances are you OO design is a bit off :)

Comment: Thanks @BlueMonkMN. I am going to try playing with the code, and see how your suggestion works out. I can visualise how that would work in my head, and it'll be good practice.